# Sound to samples is disabled

Tags: audio

I'm new to blender and one thing that sometimes happens is the 'sound to samples' menu gets disabled and I'm not sure why. What are the prerequisites for using this feature.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you have at least one keyframe of anything on your object. Then it will turn white.